# Alfresco 5 community: Reload document preview after executing onActionFormDialog doclib

Tags: javascript, java, refresh, alfresco, reload

I have written a java class similar to default `SendAsEmailActionExecuter`. In this class a pdf file is modified. After successful execute of the `doclib` action `alfresco` does not refresh preview and keeps the old one until refresh the entire page. How can I tell to alfresco reload the document preview without the need to push F5?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you simple want to refresh page using javascript there are number of ways to do that

> window.location.reload(true);

or

> window.location.reload();

or

> location.href = location.href;

If you want to update metadata, There is a out of box api "metadatarefresh" of alfresco which you can use.Two ways to use that

**Option 1:**

In side your ajax call

```
this.modules.actions.genericAction(

{

   success:

   {

     event:

      {

         name: "metadataRefresh"

      },

     .....
```

**Option 2:** Use it via bubbling

```
YAHOO.Bubbling.fire("metadataRefresh");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to refresh it through alfresco java class which extends ActionExecuterAbstractBase not javascript

Comment: AFAIK you cannot do that in java. You will have to do that in javascript.